# How do I wait for global.lastVideo to not be false?

Tags: javascript, return

Having the console log getLastVideo(channel_id) makes it spit out undefined until I call it once more. I would like to wait for global.lastVideo, which the function returns, to not be undefined before returning it's value. Any help with this or an alternative solution is highly appreciated :^)

```
    function getLastVideo(channel_id){
        client.request.parseURL(`https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=${channel_id}`)
        .then(data => {
            global.lastVideo = data.items[0].link;       
        });
        console.log('lastVideo: ' + global.lastVideo);
        return global.lastVideo;
    }
```

Comment: use async/await?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetching data from a remote address is an asynchronous action and your `console.log` and `return` statements will be executed before receiving the data.

You should make your function asynchronous and handle the logic to wait data before returning anything.

```js
function getLastVideo(channel_id){
  return client.request.parseURL(`https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=${channel_id}`)
    .then(data => {
      global.lastVideo = data.items[0].link;

      console.log('lastVideo: ' + global.lastVideo);
      return global.lastVideo;
    });
}
```

Or you can use `async/await` version

```js
async function getLastVideo(channel_id){
  const data = await client.request.parseURL(`https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=${channel_id}`);
  global.lastVideo = data.items[0].link;
  console.log('lastVideo: ' + global.lastVideo);

  return global.lastVideo;
}
```